# Powershell & XML

Tags: xml, xpath, powershell-2.0

So I hear XML is a useful format to store structured hierarchical data in.

I wrote some starter functions, but I'm having problems filtering, searching, and accessing the XML data.

See [here](http://pastebin.com/TCA8VtUs) for the functions I use to generate the test file.

My overall goal is to be able to compare like two such XML files to determine if items have been added, modified, or deleted, and list those items.

The problem I'm running into is I can't seem to get XPath to return any results. Any time I use `Select-Xml -Xpath` to search or try and filter I get no results.

As an example:

```bsh
$compobj1 = [xml](Get-Content c:\temp\test\temp.xml)
$compobj1 | Select-Xml -Xpath /Catalog/Directory |
    % {$_.node} |
    where { $_.file.name -eq $true }
```

So, C:\test with the following heirarchy

```
FolderName → Subdirectory
             first  → file.log
             second → empty(null)
             third  → test.pdf
```

Would be stored as:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='style.xsl'?>
<Catalog>
  <Date>
  <date>02/14/2017 14:02:18</date>
  </Date>
  <Directory>
    <name>first</name>
    <file>
      <name>file.log</name>
      <fullname>C:\temp\Folder\first\file.log</fullname>
      <hash>FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF</hash>
    </file>
  </Directory>
  <Directory>
    <name>second</name>
  </Directory>
  <Directory>
    <name>third</name>
    <file>
      <name>test.pdf</name>
      <fullname>C:\temp\Folder\third\test.pdf</fullname>
      <hash>FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF</hash>
    </file>
  </Directory>
</Catalog>
```

I've been at this for a couple days now, can someone point me in the right direction?

Edit: Was trying to filter nodes with the tag 'file' without much luck.

Comment: not clear what results you are trying to get but `where { $_.file.name -eq $true }`  will not return any results. try replacing `$true` with `'file.log'`

Comment: if you want all nodes with the tag 'file' then `where { $_.file }` is sufficient

Comment: The problem I am having is where {$_.file } is null. $xdoc | select-xml -Xpath "//Directory/*" provides a list of nodes one of which is file. I tack a where on and its null. I change from 'file' to any other node type thats there and its still null. I'm guessing I can't use the where-object command to filter xml requests.

Comment: to filter nodes with nulls you can use `where {$_.file -ne $null}`